# all() function not working in Firefox

Tags: javascript

In IE below line is working . popup is a div element.

```
popup.all("submenu").innerHTML = "";
```

But in other browsers below error is coming

> popup.all is not a function.

Is there any alternative for all function in other browsers.

Please suggest me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
var popup=document.getElementById('popup');
for (i in popup.childNodes) {
   if (popup.childNodes[i].nodeType == 1) {
       popup.childNodes[i].innerHTML = '';
   }
}
```

Comment: Accessing DOM elements using their id or name as a global variable is an IE proprietary feature that is considered harmful. It does not work in most browsers in standards mode, or at all in some. You should not assume that all the enumerable properties of *children* are DOM elements (or that DOM elements support the *children* property at all).

Comment: well, you could test for children[i].innerHTML, and if it exists, set it to ''... wouldn't it work?

Comment: By the way, I meant that popup was popup = document.getElementById('someElement')...
A misunderstanding... :)

Comment: If you edit your answer to include that I can give you back your point if you also use *childNodes* instead of *children* and either use a feature test for innerHTML (e.g. `if (typeof popup.childNodes[i].innerHTML == 'string')`, which is ugly) or test for `nodeType == 1` (which is better for being more direct).

Comment: Done.
By the way, I wonder whether it's ok to replace the 'if' with 
if (popup.childNodes[i].innerHTML) {}

Comment: If the element has no content, then it's innerHTML property will be an empty string, which type converts to false. But the innerHTML property is only recently standardised and is still quite different in different browsers (and likely always will be). If the element content is only white space, IE's innerHTML removes it so will return false, but Firefox's innerHTML reduces it to one space, so returns true. Does that answer the question?

Comment: @RobG let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1609/discussion-between-alex-ackerman-and-robg)

Answer (score 1):

All method is not supported by most browsers. Except IE ofcourse. Test for document.getElementById if this is false then use the "all" method.

Comment: I think the only valid use of that would be to tell anybody who is still using IE4 (or lower) that they need to upgrade their browser.

Answer (score 1):

In all browsers (including Internet Explorer) you are expected to find items by their location in the DOM tree (I'm assuming it's a DOM node given the `.innerHTML` property). You can use, for instance, [document.getElementById()](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBgQFjAA&url=https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementById&rct=j&q=mdn%20ocument.getElementById&ei=3O8jTs7_IMixhAeb3JWYAw&usg=AFQjCNEtIk735uMCuazCWqxj5GbpDL07qA&sig2=cofJLGLP5bEy_tV4phWfQg&cad=rja) and [document.getElementsByTagName()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementsByTagName). Of course, you can always store references to nodes in regular variables.

Answer (score 0):

Use `document.getElementById(elementName).innerHTML = whatever;` instead.